# Upgrading coupled Ember & Laravel projects (same folder)

Tags: laravel, ember.js, gulp, upgrade

I am currently working on a project which is using old software for the front-end and back-end frameworks.

Front-end: Ember 1.8 and back-end: Laravel 4.2.

Ember needs to be 2.5 and Laravel needs to be 5.2.

I have seen Laravelshift website for upgrading the back end which I would prefer to use due to saving time.

Now the web application is setup with Laravel and ember within the same directory.. the ember folders reside in a directory called 'client' and the Laravel files are residing under 'app'.

I have tried to upgrade Ember without completely de-coupling the projects and failed numerous times, getting errors in the terminal complaining about parsing json files - (referring to package.json / bower.json).

What is the proper way this is done? Do you have to search each dependency individually on Github and see if its compatible with the newer Ember version and install it manually?

Up till now I have used: http://emberigniter.com/update-latest-ember-data-cli/ and a couple of other guides and haven't made any progress.

I am using gulp as a task runner, when I run it to compile the project it spits out this error:

```
/Users/JCharnock/Desktop/newatp/pt2/build/js-common.js:27
var emberBuild = path.resolve(pkg.browser.ember);
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ember' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/JCharnock/Desktop/newatp/pt2/build/js-common.js:27:42)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at /Users/JCharnock/Desktop/newatp/pt2/gulpfile.js:31:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/JCharnock/Desktop/newatp/pt2/gulpfile.js:25:28)
```

Does anyone have experience with tedious tasks like this? A point in the right direction would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

To speak for the ember part, I would strongly recommend to move to `ember-cli`. I've done such a jump recently, and to be honest, it was a *lot* of work!

Generally what you should try is to jump to ember 1.13 first if its possible, and then jump over the 2.0 mark. This because if you have your up running on 1.13 without any deprecations it will also run under 2.x!

So best is probably this order:

- First move to ember 1.13, disable everything that depends on other plugins
- Then move to ember-cli
- Then jump to ember 2.x
- Rebuild all plugin stuff

---

The other way to go, and what I did is to start from a new `ember-cli` application and integrate your old code file by file. This is probably the better solution if you have to change a lot, and if you move to ES6 modules you *will* have to touch each file.

The downside is that you won't get the nice deprecations from 1.13, your app might just stop working. So you can't do this for your hole app, but have to do it file by file. For me it was a week just sitting down and doing it, transferring a component, test it, fix it, next.

Its a big jump. Good luck.